# Which would be the correct software license

Tags: open-source, licensing

i developed some software and i like provide is as open source for private use only. It's should not be allowed to distribute the software in a commercial without my allowance.

What would be the best license for the software? Is there some standard license which fulfill my requirements?

Comment: Hi there! Your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow since it is not a direct, programming related issue, but rather about licensing. You may be able to get an answer at [Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com). Be sure to read their on-topic page too. :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is such license. You just want to add a [Copyright Notice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_notice) ([all rights reserved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_rights_reserved)).

You want the license to be open-source, but it will violate the definition of "open-source" if you don't allow it to be completely open-source.

Answer (score -1):

opensource.org says:

> Can Open Source software be used for commercial purposes?
>
> Absolutely.
>   All Open Source software can be used for commercial purpose; the Open
>   Source Definition guarantees this. You can even sell Open Source
>   software.
>   However, note that commercial is not the same as proprietary. [...]
>
> Can I restrict how people use an Open Source licensed program?
>
> No. The freedom to use the program for any purpose is part of the Open
>   Source Definition. Open source licenses do not discriminate against
>   fields of endeavor. [...]

See these links:

Faq: http://opensource.org/faq#commercial

Licenses & Standards: https://opensource.org/licenses